# drawImage() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, drawimage

When I draw a line, it is drawn and appears fine, but when I draw a new line again, the last thing I drew disappears. It's like resetting after I draw a new line again.

Here's my code:

```
  function draw() {
      var teethImage = new Image();
      teethImage.onload = function () {
      };
      teethImage.src = "images/teeth.png";
      ctx.drawImage(teethImage, 1, 1);
      ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
      ctx.strokeStyle = x;
      ctx.lineWidth = y;
      ctx.stroke();
  }
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: firstly you can try to moving code into `teethImage.onload`.

Comment: i've already done that, but i cannot draw already, it appears like a point/dot instead of line or something.

Comment: try move beginning point(`moveTo(startX,startY)`) before `ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);`

Comment: moveTo(startX,startY)? where did you get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed the error. I just simply load the image on the init().
Because the reason why it is resetting, it displays again a new image, thus, it overwrites the image.

Answer (score 0):

here try this:

```
draw();

function draw() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {
       ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1);

       ctx.moveTo(0,0); // startX,startY (i mean 'start point which you want:x, start point which you want:y')
       ctx.lineTo(img.width, img.height);
       ctx.lineTo(img.width/3, img.height/2);
       ctx.lineTo(img.width, 0);
       ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff'; //you used (strokeStyle(x), what is x)
       ctx.lineWidth = 7;
       ctx.stroke();
    };

    img.src = "http://bermangraphics.com/images/jury-images-13.jpg";
}
```

You can examine [strokeStyle](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_strokestyle.asp)

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enginustun/fhjtt5tb/)